# Excel formula to calculate YTD metrics by detecting current month

Tags: excel

I have two excel tables - 2015 sales and 2014 sales in the following format. And a third table called Year over Year Variance which looks at % change in 2015 over 2014.

```
2015          Jan     Feb    Mar .... YTD (total)
Orders
Revenue
...
...

2014          Jan     Feb    Mar .... YTD (total)
Orders
Revenue
...
...

Variance      Jan     Feb    Mar .... YTD
Orders
Revenue
...
...
```

Computing Jan variance over Jan or Feb variance over Feb is simple. How do I compute Year to date variance. Because the 2014 table is already populated for the whole year - so the last column is the sum of 12 months of data.

For 2015, I only have Jan and Feb. So the variance column for Year to date should be (Jan+Feb 2015)/(Jan+Feb 2014). How do I write a formula to check for the current month and then sum only those two months for the year to date calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Excel formulas (no-VBA), you can couple the `SUM`, `OFFSET`, and `COUNT` functions to calculate the variance. In the simplified formula below, Row 1 is fully populated across all 12 months. Row 2 is only populated for 2 months. Using the `COUNT` formula across the range, the OFFSET will expand the width based on the number of populated rows.

Let me know if you have any problems adapting it.

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$2,0,0,1,COUNT($A$2:$L$2)))/SUM(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,1,COUNT($A$2:$L$2)))
```

Comment: Thanks, the formula works but the result is wrong. So I guess I'm missing some logic. Since my col A has text as in the sample above, my formula is based on column B. My 2014 data is in cell B51:M51 my 2015 data is in B3:M3. Here is my formula - `=SUM(OFFSET($B$3,0,0,1,COUNT($B$3:$M$3)))/SUM(OFFSET($B$51,0,0,1,COUNT($B$51:$M$51)))`. Based on manual calculation the % I get is different from what the formala gives me. Does the formula look right? What does the 0,0,1 do?

Comment: @Moosa You're pretty close. The `COUNT` within BOTH of the `OFFSET` functions should refer to 2015 data: `COUNT($B$3:$M$3)`. The `OFFSET` function works as such: Starting Cell is where to start, 0: row offset (move up or down), 0: column offset move left or right), 1: row height (how many rows to include), column height (how many columns). In our case, we start at cell B3, move 0 cells down, 0 cells to right or left, include only 1 row, and include columns based on the count of data in 2015's row. Does this help to clarify?

Comment: Thanks. I missed that both counts were the same range. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
=Month(Today())
```

will return the current month (integer, 1-12) in the spreadsheet.

```
Month(Now)
```

will do the same thing in VBA code.

I'd use a formula in the 3rd table along the lines of

```
=if(Month(Today())<=Month(*date-of-column-header*), *Computed-Variance*, 0)
```

That way, you simply have zero show up in the cells where the comparison makes no sense, and your sum of the numbers in the row is unaffected.

Comment: Thanks, i know that but how do i write the formula IF forumla?

Comment: Edited with that info.